# USB battery charger and GPIO power supply schematic for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, eaglecad, charging, lipo, ups

I'm trying to design a circuit in Eagle to provide reliable + safe battery power to a Raspberry Pi via the GPIO pins.

The requirements are:

- Accept power input via micro USB (separate from the Pi).
- Intelligently charge a large Lithium-
  Ion battery like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/products/353) one.
- Provide a regulated 5V output with up to 1A current draw.
- Provide a fuse on the output to safeguard against accidental shorts on the Pi.
- Continuously power the Pi without interruption when supply connected/disconnected.
- Use small number of easily obtainable components (preferable via Adafruit or Sparkfun)
- Simple to understand
- Easy to solder (no microscopic SMDs, larger SMDs OK)

I know this is probably an easy design for many of you out there, and it's well beyond my knowledge, so hence me asking here. I also feel it would be really nice to have this circuit publicly available online.

A schematic with a list of part numbers will win the green tick plus my eternal gratitude :). I know there are many people looking for a pluggable solution like this for their circuit designs so an actual Eagle file gets extra points.

PS: to be clear - I am not looking for a prefabricated solution to purchase. Specifically looking for a schematic that can be added to a Eagle project.

PPS: the [schematic for the PowerCell](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11231) from Sparkfun might be a good place to start, however it has a max output of 600mA, may or may not provide UPS capability, doesn't have the fuse, and looks a bit complicated to solder.

PPPS: Power management IC's like the [LTC3586](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3586) look promising but they seem to only come in microscopic packages.

Comment: As what you are describing is a portable electronics requirement, most modern solutions will indeed be in high density packages suitable at least for use in a tablet if not a phone.  Keep in mind that a pi is a poor choice for a battery powered system anyway, as its heritage to line powered set top boxes rather than mobile applications means it isn't really set up to dynamically adjust its consumption in accordance with need or to effectively sleep and re-awake.

Comment: Thanks Chris, do you think an IC like the LTC3586 would be impossible for an amateur to solder? It's in a 4x6mm QFN package.